# Regex for validating a JSON map with optional variables

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate the JSON responses from calls to a web service.

There are 13 total variables that may or may not be passed back in a mapping like this:

```
{"var1":"val1","var2":"val2","var3":"val3", ... "var13":"val13"}
```

The longest possible response could have all thirteen variables, but a typical response is more like this:

```
{"var4":"val4","var6":"val6","var10","val10"}
```

I need to write regex that can capture the values so that they can be set to individual variables in the receiving system.

Optional non-capture groups, optional capture groups, making every character optional

If all 13 variables were present in every API response, the following regex would work perfectly:

```
\{"var1":"?(.*?)"?,"var2":"?(.*?)"?,"var3":"?(.*?)"?,"var4":"?(.*?)"?,"var5":"?(.*?)"?,"var6":"?(.*?)"?,"var7":"?(.*?)"?,"var8":"?(.*?)"?,"var9":"?(.*?)"?,"var10":"?(.*?)"?,"var11":"?(.*?)"?,"var12":"?(.*?)"?,"var13":"?(.*?)"?\}
```

I have tried a lot of different combinations, like wrapping the variables in optional, non-capture groups, for example:

```
\{(:?"var1":)?"?(.*?)"?,? ... \}
```

And making the capture group itself optional as well:

```
\{(:?"var1":)?"?(.*?)?"?,? ... \}
```

All the way to making every character optional:

```
\{"?v?a?r?1?"?:?"?(.*?)?"?,? ... \}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why not just parse the JSON?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Does it not have anything to parse JSON?

Comment: Make a pattern for one variable, and then quantify it with `{1,13}` to specify that it can appear between 1 and 13 times.

Comment: And I assume `"var10","val10"` in your examp[le is a typo.

Comment: Can't parse the JSON normally because this isn't actually being done in code - it's for a Five9 telephony integration. When you make API calls in Five9, the interface provided only lets you deconstruct the response with Regex. I've been fighting them on this being a terrible solution for a year.

Answer (score 1):

Use a quantifier to specify the range of times the same pattern can appear:

```
\{"[^"]":"[^"]*"(?:,"[^"]+":"[^"]*"){0,12}\}
```

`"[^"]+":"[^"]*"` matches a single `"var":"val"` pair. I'm assuming your variables and values will not include nested double quotes (there might be a way to allow escaped quotes using lookbehind, but I'm not sure how to code it). It requires at least one of these, then allows up to 12 additional ones with between them.

But doing it this way seems very fragile. In addition to the problem of nested quotes, I haven't allowed for optional whitespace, I'm assuming a rigid format. The right way to do this is to parse the JSON and then test the resulting object. JSON parsers are available in most languages.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that a regex is not a good solution, upvote from me!